# BFS for modified shortest path

Tags: c++, graph, time-limit-exceeded, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

> Given **K** descriptions for bus line paths that exists to lead students between **N** campuses. What is the minimum cost that a student will have to goes from campus 1 to campus N ?
>
> The itinerary of each path **L** is a sequence of |**L**|( ≥ 2 ) campuses {C1, C2, …, CL}, and each line has only one bus, which passes by all campuses of the line, following the itinerary order, stopping in each of them and making a U-turn whenever it reaches an endpoint of the itinerary, reversing the itinerary order. The transport pass costs 1$, and has to be paid by the passenger while getting onto the bus, no matter the time the passenger is going to stay in it.
>
> Input:
>
> > The first input line consists of two integers **N** and **K** (2 ≤ N ≤ 10^4, 1 ≤ K ≤ 10^3), which represent respectively the number of campuses and the number of public transport lines created by UFFS. Each one of the **K** input lines following describes a transport line **L** and consists of the integer |**L**| (2 ≤ |**L**| ≤ 10^2) followed by the |**L**| identifiers **Ci** (1 ≤ Ci ≤ N, 1 ≤ i ≤ |L|) of the campuses by which the ship passes, wherein C1 and C|L| are the endpoints of L. For every campus A and every campus B it is guaranteed that it is possible to go from A to B.
>
> Output:
>
> > Output the minimum cost to go from campus 1 to campus N.

To solve this i've tried a BFS. Each node has its distance updated. The algorithm takes the minimum distance found.

The code is easy to understand ?

I'm getting time limit exceeded on the judge that has [this problem](http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1908_en.html). How can i make this solution faster ?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string.h>

struct Edge{
    int d,t,c; //distance , target and color
    Edge(int _d,int _t ,int _c):d(_d),t(_t),c(_c){}
    Edge(int _t, int _c):d(0),t(_t),c(_c){}
};

using adj_list = std::vector<Edge>    ;
using graph    = std::vector<adj_list>;

unsigned int BFS(graph &g, int source, int target, int max_colors){
    
    //init visited as false for every node
    bool visited[g.size()][max_colors];
    memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited));
    
    //put the source with an unexistent color(forcing int to buy all possible colors) and distance=0
    std::queue<Edge> q;
    q.push(Edge(0,source,0));
    
    unsigned int shortest_path = -1; //infinity
    while (!q.empty()) {
        Edge e = q.front();
        q.pop();

        //this path is already bigger than the minimum one
        if(e.d > mini)
            continue;
        
        if(e.t == target){ //target node was found
            shortest_path = e.d < shortest_path ? e.d : shortest_path;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(visited[e.t][e.c])
            continue;
        
        visited[e.t][e.c] = true;
        
        adj_list &adj_u = g[e.t];
        for (auto &v : adj_u) {
            //distance from adjacent node increases if its color is
            //different from the visited node color...
            //the target and color keeps the same
            q.push(Edge(e.d + (v.c != e.c), v.t, v.c));
        }
    }
    
    return shortest_path;
}


int main(void) {
    int n,k;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    
    graph g(n + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        int l,u,v;
        scanf("%d %d %d",&l,&u,&v);
    
        g[u].push_back(Edge(v,i));
        g[v].push_back(Edge(u,i));
        for (int j = 2; j < l; ++j) {
            u = v;
            scanf("%d",&v);
            g[u].push_back(Edge(v,i));
            g[v].push_back(Edge(u,i));
        }
    }

    
    /*
     for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i) {
     printf("%d : ",i);
     for (int j = 0; j < g[i].size(); ++j) {
     printf("%d -> ",g[i][j].t);
     }
     printf("\\ \n");
     }
     */
    
    printf("%u\n",BFS(g, 1, n, k + 1));
}
```

For example consider the following input:

[image: Bus lines]

```
9 4
6 2 3 4 6 7 9
4 1 3 4 5
3 8 3 4
2 9 8
```

For this case the minimum cost is 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Push bus lines, not edges

I feel like your breadth first search could be improved if instead of pushing single edges onto your queue, you pushed a whole bus line.  After all, the distance you are finding is the number of bus lines traversed, not the number of edges.  So a pseudocode algorithm would be:

```
foreach (busline b connected to vertex 0) {
    visited_busline[b] = true;
    q.push(b, 1);  // 1 = distance
}
visited_vertex[0] = true;

while (q.notEmpty()) {
    busline, distance = q.pop();

    foreach (vertex v in busline) {
        if (v == target) {
            return distance;
        }
        if (visited_vertex[v]) {
            continue;
        }
        visited_vertex[v] = true;
        foreach (busline b connected to v) {
            if (!visited_busline[b]) {
                visited_busline[b] = true;
                q.push(b, distance+1);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then all that is left it to parse the original input so that each vertex v contains a list of bus lines that it is connected to.

## Typo

This code didn't compile for me:

> ```
>     if(e.d > mini)
>         continue;
> ```

I believe that at some point, you changed `mini` to `shortest_path`.  Also, in this line, I believe that you can use `>=` which can help a little in reducing your search depth by 1 level:

```
    if(e.d >= shortest_path)
        continue;
```

Comment: I've added the e.d > mini while i was writing the post =) I will try to follow your idea.